# Finding eigenvalues using triangulars

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I understand that if a matrix is a triangular, then the diagonal entries are eigenvalues of the matrix. If I row reduce any matrix to its triangular format, have I found all of the eingenvalues?

Answer (score 4):

The diagonal entries of a triangular matrix are its eigenvalues. But it doesn't follow that row-reducing a general matrix helps compute the eigenvalues: if $M$ is an arbitrary matrix, then row-reduction gives

$$EM = U$$
where $E$ is a product of elementary matrices and $U$ is upper-triangular. Now you know the eigenvalues of $EM$, but this doesn't tell you anything about the eigenvalues of $M$.

Answer (score 2):

If you write for the row-reducing process the matrix equation using the letters as in user7530's answer
$$ EM = U \qquad \qquad \text{ this alters the eigenvalues of }M$$ 
then a ***correct*** solution which ***preserves the eigenvalues*** were, if you do a ***similaritiy transform***.
Thus if you found some $E$ instead such that
$$ EME^{-1} = U \qquad \qquad \text{ this preserves the eigenvalues of }M \tag 1$$ 
then the eigenvalues are preserved.

But for this case, $E$ is not easy to find. However I think I remember an iterative process, with which you can find (="approximate") $E$:

---

Step 0: Let $B_0 = M$
Step 1: Then find $E_0$ (by your set of row-reduction-operations) such that $$ E_0 B_0 = U_0 \qquad \qquad U_0 \text{ is triangular } \tag 2$$
Step 2: Then compute $ B_1 = E_0 B_0 E_0^{-1} $

Step 3: Then find $E_1$ (by your set of row-reduction-operations) such that $$ E_1 B_1 = U_1 \qquad \qquad U_1 \text{ is triangular }$$
Step 4: and iterate from step 2.

---

This should approximate $B_\infty$ to a triangular matrix with the same eigenvalues as $M$. The product $ E  = \cdots E_2 E_1 E_0 $ gives then
$$ E M E^{-1} = B  \qquad \qquad B \text{ is triangular in the limit with eigenvalues of } M$$

Addendum: If you take care, that the $E_k$ are rotation-matrices (=orthogonal) you can replace the matrix inversion of $E^{-1}$ by transposition $E^T$  only

Here is a picture of the iteration-process. All matrices are 4x4; the iterated $B_k$ matrices are in the left 4x4-column, the $U_k$ matrices in the second 4x4-columns; the $E_k$ matrices in the third column and the $E$ matrix as the running partial product in the last column. Ten iterations were needed to approximate $B_{10}$ to triangular shape with 2 dec digits visible:

> ```
>     $B_k$             $U_k$                $E_k$                $E$
> ```
>
> [image: picture]

Answer (score 0):

If a matrix can be row reduced into a triangular form, then you have the eigenvalues already.

$BUT$ every matrix can't be reduced into a triangular form.

They can be factorized into two matrices, a lower triangular and upper triangular (by LU factorization, you might be aware of it already). But, the diagonals of those matrices won't give you eigenvalues.

$Ax = \lambda x$ OR characteristic equation det|A -$\lambda$I| = 0 must be solved to find the eigenvalues

Also, there are other methods to find the complete eigensystem for a matrix.